# google map api getting XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document error

Tags: php, mysql, api, google-maps, xml-parsing

I am using google maps api on this link https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 and trying to use it with my database. But when i run this php code i get errors.

here is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `PID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=36 ;
```

here is php code that i modified:

```
<?php  

require("dbinfo.php"); 

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Select all the rows in the users table

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("latitude", $row['latitude']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("longitude", $row['longitude']);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("time", $row['time']);
} 

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

and this is the error when i run this php code:

```
This page contains the following errors:   
error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I think problem caused by "time", but i couldn't figure it out how to solve this.
Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost 10 hours trying to find error, here is what it is painful error: 
I forget empty space in dbinfo.php file just before opening php tag!!!!

```
 <?php
$host="localhost";
$username="abc";
$password="abc";
$database="abc";
?>
```

case closed...